# How to plot Images(in PIL-Format) in Python out of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to plot a bunch of images in a grid/tile-style view. I want to distribute 7 different images into 144 Tiles randomly.

---

My current status is:

---

The 7 images (3 for this test) are read into the script via PIL Image.open(). Then I insert the images randomly into a dataframe(16x9). Afterwards i want to plot the images out of this data frame via imshow().

```
matrix = np.random.randint(low=0, high=7, size=(16, 9))
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)

test1 = Image.open('test1.jpg')
test2 = Image.open('test2.jpg')
test3 = Image.open('test3.jpg')

test1 = plt.imshow(test1)
test2 = plt.imshow(test2)
test3 = plt.imshow(test3)

df = df.replace([0],test1)
df = df.replace([1],test2)
df = df.replace([2],test3)
df = df.replace([3],test1)
df = df.replace([4],test2)
df = df.replace([5],test3)
df = df.replace([6],test3)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.imshow(df)
```

[My current dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpihV.png)

Does anyone know how to plot these images out of the data frame? Or is there maybe another solution to arrange and randomise the images?

---

Thank you!

Comment: Use subplots and imshow.  Simply iterate through your images and put each one in a new subplot.

Comment: Yes, that was my plan. But unfortunately imshow cannot work with the images in my data frame and the PIL-Format. I get the error: TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

Comment: Your example shows you trying to plot the whole dataframe.  I’m suggesting that you use subplots and use imshow on the images.  imshow has no trouble with PIL images.

Comment: Ok i understand. If its not to much of an expense, could you give me an example how to iterate through the images?

Comment: Sure, I typed up a quick answer that should get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is from passing the dataframe directly to plt.imshow().  plt.imshow() expects to see images.  So, I would simply iterate over the dataframe and pass images into subplots of plt.imshow() one at a time.  I'm not randomizing anything here, as that's not the issue that's giving you trouble.

FWIW, I think storing the images into a dataframe only complicates the task (why not just work with a list of images directly?), but I assume you have reasons for doing it so I will keep that aspect in my solution.

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filenames = [['image1.jpg', 'image2.png'],
             ['image3.png', 'image4.jpg']
             ]
images = [[Image.open(fn) for fn in row] for row in filenames]

df = pd.DataFrame(images)

nrows = len(df.index)
ncols = len(df.columns)
plotindex = 1
for row in df.index:
    for col in df.columns:
        plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, plotindex)
        plt.imshow(df[row][col])
        plt.axis('off')
        plotindex += 1

plt.show()
```